# Data Cleanse ENTIRE Access Table of Specific Value (SQL Update Query Issues)

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, data-cleaning

I've been searching for a quick way to do this after my first few thoughts have failed me, but I haven't found anything.

### My Issue

I'm importing raw client data into an Access database where the flat file they provide is parsed and converted into a standardized format for our organization. I do this for all of our clients, but this particular client's software gives us a file that puts "(NULL)" in every field that should be NULL. lol as a result, I have a ton of strings rather than a null field!

My goal is to do a data cleanse of the entire TABLE, rather than perform the cleanse at the FIELD level (as I do in my temporary solution below).

### Data Cleanse

**Temporary Solution:**

I can't add those strings to our datawarehouse, so for now, I just have a query with an IIF statement check that replaces "(NULL)" with "" for each field (which took awhile to setup since the client file has roughly 96 fields). This works. However, we work with hundreds of clients, so I'd like to make a scale-able solution that doesn't require many changes if another client has a similar file; not to mention that if this client changes something in their file, I might have to redo my field specific statements.

**Long-term Solution:**

My first thought was an UPDATE query. I was hoping I could do something like:

```
UPDATE [ImportedRaw_T]
SET [ImportedRaw_T].* = ""
WHERE ((([ImportedRaw_T].* = "(NULL)"));
```

This would be easily scale-able, since for further clients I'd only need to change the table name and replace "(NULL)" with their particular default. Unfortunately, you can't use SELECT * with an update query.

Can anyone think of a work-around to the SELECT * issue for the update query, or have a better solution for cleansing an entire table, rather doing the cleanse at the field level?

***SIDE NOTES***

1. This conversion is 100% automated currently (Access is called via a watch folder batch), so anything requiring manual data manipulation / human intervention is out.
2. I've tried using a batch script to just cleanse the data in the .txt file before importing to Access - however, this caused an issue with the fixed-width format of the .txt, which has caused even larger issues with the automatic import of the file to Access. So I'd prefer to do this in Access if possible.

Any thoughts and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does your automated process start an Access application instance to load and convert the new data?

Comment: Even with fixed-width format (shudder), shouldn't replacing `(NULL)` by six spaces do the trick?

Comment: @HansUp - yes, a batch script opens Access - then a macro (called during that same batch step) executes the import, conversion, and export of a converted file.

Comment: @Andre - Unfortunately I've tried that as well, and no luck. Using batch before my import, I've tried a `replace "(NULL)" with ""` and `replace "(NULL)" with "      "` and no luck -- still causing an import issue where the delimiter isn't detected properly each time.

Comment: I meant neither `""` nor `" "` but `"      "` to keep the string length constant ("NULL" is 6 characters). [edit: you probably meant this, comments don't display multiple spaces :-( ]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's impossible to implement this in SQL using wildcards instead of column names, there is no such kind syntax.

I would suggest VBA solution, where you need to cycle thru all table fields and if  field data type is string, generate and execute SQL `UPDATE` command for updating current field.

Also use `Null` instead of `""`, if you really need Nulls in the field instead of empty strings, they may work differently in calculations.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this (not because it won't be compatible with staying 100% automated, but because it seemed less efficient that an update query / being generic across multiple clients and iterations) - however, I'm actually a fan of VBA, so this might be the next stuff. If I go VBA I'll post an example solution with some general code for further question viewers. Thanks for the input @sergey!

Comment: This will (automatically) create 96 UPDATE statements, but that can't be avoided once you are working on the table - you need a separate SET and WHERE clause for each column.